Cannot access configuration for ruff via lspconfig
I am using ruff, ruff-lsp, pyright and using the distro Astrovim. Whenever I open a file, I get the following warning,
[lspconfig] Cannot access configuration for ruff. Ensure this server is listed in `server_configurations.md` or added as a custom server.

I checked the server_configurations.md (https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md), ruff is mentioned in the document. But when I check locally with :h lspconfig-all, I don't see ruff in there, so I guess the warning is justified? How can I get rid of this warning? I tried updating the plugin nvim-lspconfig and all the packages but it didn't help. Also I would like understand, why this warning is getting generated or what's happening, so any related documents are much appreciated.

Have you checked the specific documentation for LSP configuration with AstroNvim bundle ? It uses AstroLSP, the AstroNvim language server configuration engine plugin, based on lspconfig plugin to configure LSP servers => https://docs.astronvim.com/recipes/advanced_lsp
